# 8 bit SPI Microcontorller interface with 16 bit SPI slave

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, spi, atmega328p

I'm willing to use the Atmega328 microcontroller to control the AD9833 waveform generator through the SPI interface of the microcontroller; the only problem is that the AD9833 reads 16-bit data while the microcontroller's SPI is 8-bit based.

I have been told that the most intuitive solution to this (sending two consecutive bytes) doesn't work, ¿is this true?

If it is, ¿is there anyway I could interface the two devices in order to implement the communication?

Comment: Somebody told you that sending 2 bytes would not work.  He seems to have some insights.  Wouldn't it make sense to ask *that same person* as to *why* it doesn't work?

Comment: Look at the AD9833 Datasheet, SPI normaly just has a clock and mosi miso pins. Maybe it works just sending two bytes. If this is not the case you can make a spi interface with software producing the clock on your own. Its really easy and straightforward coding your own spi. Just needs a simple function

Comment: Yes, the reason is that loading a new byte to the register that contains the data to be sent causes a desynchronization, eventhough the loading takes a very low time, it supposedly ruins the protocol

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet answers this in the section about interfacing to an 68HC11 series microcontroller on page 20 of the datasheet:

[image: 8 bit spi interface]

You just need to keep fsync low, and send another 8 bit data stream to the device.

Comment: The problem comes with the SPI module of the atmega328, where it says that after sending one byte the SCK generator stops, so, there will be a period where no clock is generated between the end of the first byte and the beginning of the second one, I don't know how the AD9833 will react to this

Comment: @JsMartinez That should not matter, it will still just sit in whatever you have defined the idle state to be for the clock line.  The AD9833 should not care one bit whether your internal clock generator has stopped.

Comment: @JsMartinez I am guessing "the person" who told you this wouldn't work was raising the FSYNC line in his spi send function, messing with his transmissions.